# Stored Procedure to get and validate data from same table using mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am new to mysql and DB concept and stuck in Stored Procedures.

I have requirement to work on logic to get, validate, process data from same table and insert into another table.

Every row has columns name, code, starttime(DD/int), duration(hrs/int), startwith, startafter and so on.

My requirement is to write stored procedure
 with conditions of looping table records
Condition 1:
  if starttime is not null in table A then insert into table B with name, code, startTime(timestamp, computed from starttime), endtime(timestamp , computed from duration), startwith, startafter

Condition 2:
  if any row has startwith or startafter and its matches with code from previous inserted rows then in insert in tbl B with keeping start time of row 2 after previous inserted row endtime

Need to check this with every row.
'startwith' and 'startafter' can be present in multiple rows with same 'code'

Condition:
only any of  'starttime', 'startwith', 'startafter' column will be not null

```
'Name' 'code' 'starton'     'starttime',    'startwith',      'startafter'  'Duration'
 ABC  abc_efg     03          9               null              null          10
nfg  cpd_hnb     null        null            null               abc_efg       20
gfg  dfd_hab     null        null           abc_efg             cpd_hnb       5
gdf  ergd_hab    19         null           cpd_hnb             null          11
```

Was looking for array approach, but not possible in mysql.
Denied for cursors as they are problematic.
Working with 'temp tables' and looping data but not really getting desired results. maybe my queries are not really working right
no success with selfjoins as well.
I am able to create time and do validation but not able to get desired results, however single row is getting inserted.

i want to push this way
Name   code         startdate       endDate
'ABC', 'abc_efg', '2010-03-03 09:00:00', '2010-07-19 23:59:00'

Comment: Condition 2's last cluase is not clear. Kindly include create state and insert statements  in question and show desired output also

Comment: Need to traverse entire table and see if previous processed row's code is not equal to either 'statuswith' or 'startafter'. I.e row 1 code can equal to of 'startwith' in row3 and equal to ,'startafter' of row 4. In this case i will have to put starttime as per dependent value.